# 'Number' input parameter can not be used by algorithms in Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis-3, parameters, qgis-modeler

Does anybody knows why I use the Graphical Modeler in QGIS 3.0, the 'Number'  input parameter can not be used by  algorithms, I have tried the algorithms of 'Buffer', 'create grid' and others, but they can not use the 'Number' parameter I create as the below picture:
(I am not good at English, I hope I describe my question clearly)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:**

You have to use `@thisisanumber` as Distance value. Parameter name in Parameter Definition window can include spaces, but you shouldn't use those spaces in tool window.

[image]

**Solution 2 for newer versions:**

You can easily select any "Number" input as parameter using "Model Input" option by clicking button on the right side of the parameter.

[image]